# Twilio Programmable Chat - Best Strategy for Generating Summary of Multiple Channels

Tags: twilio

We have a mobile app where each user may have a number of connections, and a unique chat channel with each of them. In our "message summary screen" we would like to show a list containing only the last message from each channel, so if they have 10 connections, the list would show to 10 messages (assuming they had already initiated a conversation with each connection.)  We have a couple ideas how to do this.

First, would be to join each channel, get the message history, then compile the summary list once all the data is available.  The issue with this method seems to be that first, its pretty slow to join many channels and get the message history.  Second, getting messages from each channel is it's own asynchronous request, so there are potential race condition situations as well.

The next idea is to use webhooks, to monitor every message coming into the system and add them to a database for the applicable user as needed.  This would allow the "summary" request to respond very fast since there would be no need to join channels.  However, we are concerned that as the user base grows, this method could cause scaling difficulties with things like database size, throughput, etc.

Can anyone recommend either of these options, or a third method is recommended for creating the type of screen we are looking to build?  Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: We build our own managed Chat objects in our database and I would strongly recommend AGAINST it.  It's very difficult to make it robust.

It looks like the API has since been upgraded and you can get the channel attributes when you get all the channels you're in, and there is a paginator for them and everything.  I would create a webhook that catches all messages sent and adds a 'lastMessage' attribute to the channel objects.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing your experience.